# sync inventory of Shopify and Magento 1 real time

Tags: magento, synchronization, shopify, integration, inventory

I need help of experts I have two stores, one is on Shopify and another is on Magento 1. I'm facing problem to manage stock reports because I have one inventory but two stores. How can I sync both stores in real-time like when I get an order and I delivered that so automatically product will less in both stores. I have already tried some third-party integration tools, but they don't work realtime can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop a third party application to create an private app for inventory [webhooks](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/events/webhook) for Shopify and create event/observer on the product update and order create in Magento.